# How can I programmatically check if a file is a valid PDF document in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdftron

In my app, I have a button that allows the user to pick a PDF file from the external downloads folder. My code for that is shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_PDF);
```

I also have a screenshot of the file picker intent:

[image]

Once the user picks a file, I run the code below in OnActivityResult:

```
if (requestCode == IMPORT_PDF) {
    Uri uri;
    if (data != null) {
        // get uri of selected file
        uri = data.getData();
```

And I proceed to use the file's URI to open it in a PDF viewer that I integrated into my app (PDFTron), and I have already tested that the PDF viewer works.

Here's the problem: When the PDF is of "invalid format" and I try to open it in my app, I get the following error and the PDF viewer crashes:

```
W/System.err: Exception: 
     Message: PDF header not found. The file is not a valid PDF document.
```

Is there any way to check if a PDF file is of invalid format programmatically before I try to open it in my PDF viewer?

Comment: That depends a lot on the definition of "invalid format". You have no good way of knowing how PDFTron defines that, beyond "PDF header not found". You would have to look at [documentation for the PDF format](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/pdf-file-format-basic-structure/) and come up with an algorithm for validating the header. Or, use some PDF-reading library (like [this one](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android)) and see if it can read the PDF.

Comment: Most likely what you are trying to load is not actually a PDF file. Can you post one of these problematic PDF files here for review? If you cannot (confidential) then you submit to PDFTron support directly.